# how to map background image in div tag

Tags: html, css, area

I wanted to create a box that you could click on and be forwarded to "#" so I thought this would be a good idea:

But unfortuneatly areamaps couldn't be used in div or p tags :/
Anyone have an idea what a good solution would be?

Comment: sorry left my code <div style = "background:url(image.jpg)" usemap = "#map">
</div>
<map>
<area href = "#" coords = "20,20,180,180"
</map>

Comment: I think this is likely to be a http://doctype.com/ -question.

Comment: Not sure but I think `usemap` is only valid on images

Comment: Yes, usemaps can not be used in tags. its only for images.

Comment: And the object element but the support of object[usemap] is awful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not php related, because its happening in the navigator.
Use javascript instead :

```
<div style='background:url(image.jpg)' onclick='function(){document.location.replace="#"}'> </div>
```

Comment: It wasn't clear you wanted to match an area.
I still think javascript is your solution.
One raw method would be to check the mouse position of the cursor in the anonym function matched to the onclick.event.
Javascript/jQuery has a function to retrieve the cursor position, see http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Mouse_Position.
Again, you can check the real position of your div, therefore you have the position of your bg image.
At last just do two lines of maths with a if(), to check if your cursor is within your bg image and to redirect if it is.

Answer (score 1):

You could create  tags inside the div. You can give these subtags and id or you apply the style in the tag's style attribute. Set the tags style to display:block and position the link via position:absolute or position:relative and the attributes top:5px and left:5px. Set width and height and top and left appropriately.